# Why "%I64d" is giving strange output when it is used multiple times in same format string?

Tags: c++, c

While I was solving a programming problem on codeforces, I found that when the format specifier `"%I64d"` was used multiple times in same format string like:

```
long long int a, b, c;
a = 1, b = 3, c = 5; 
printf("%I64d %I64d %I64d\n", a, b, c);
```

the output was

```
                                                               1                                                                0                                                                3
```

However when I separated each specifier, like:

```
long long int a, b, c;
a = 1, b = 3, c = 5;
printf("%I64d ", a);
printf("%I64d ", b);
printf("%I64d ", c);
puts("");
```

the output was, as expected:

```
                                                           1                                                                3                                                                5
```

Here is the ideone link to see above code snippets in action:
http://ideone.com/f2udRB

Please help me to understand why this is happening? If this is undefined behaviour, how such an output is shown? How can I understand the reasons when sometimes such unexpected outputs are shown?

Comment: `%I64d` is a Microsoft-ism.  Use `%lld` (that's ell-ell-dee)

Comment: Thanks, but codeforces raises warning when I try to submit using     %lld. I can use     %lld, but I was curious why and how such an output is shows in above case.

Comment: With `%I64d` printf expects a 4-byte number on the stack. But you are pushing 8-byte numbers, since a/b/c are `long long`. The numbers are below 2^32, so on the stack you see (in 4-byte-steps) "1 0 3 0 5 0". Only the first 3 numbers are read by printf, the rest is discarded. When you use `%lld`, printf correctly interprets the stack data as 8-byte numbers.

Comment: @ctx Why would `%I64d` expect a 4-byte number?

Comment: @CodyGray With gnu printf `I` means, "use alternative output digits" and the `64` means "pad to 64 chars". The remaining `d` stands for an signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: @Ctx you should make it an answer

Comment: @Ctx; Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Did not your compiler give warnings about `printf("%I64d %I64d %I64d\n", a, b, c);`?  You may want to check that the warning level of your compiler is set to it highest level - saves time.

Comment: the real question is why are you still using printf in 2016??

Comment: @UmNyobe: 'cos it's a lot easier to control than iostream?  (Plus, iostream is a *nightmare* for I18N.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the format string `%I64d` `printf()` expects a 4-byte number on the stack, since with GNU printf `I` means, "use alternative output digits" and the `64` means "pad to 64 chars". The remaining `d` stands for an signed 32-bit integer.

But you are pushing 8-byte numbers, since `a, b, c` are of type `long long`.

The numbers are below 2^32, so on the stack you see (in 4-byte-steps)

```
1 0 3 0 5 0
```

Only the first 3 numbers are interpreted by printf, the rest is discarded. When you use `%lld`, `printf()` correctly interprets the stack data as 8-byte numbers.

Answer (score 3):

> Please help me to understand why this is happening? If this is
>   undefined behaviour, how such an output is shown?

Yes, the behavior is undefined, but the reason of different output is due to *calling conventions*. The ideone compiler is running at 32-bit, which means that parameters are passed on stack (according to the System V ABI) instead of registers. You may see that dissassembly of the code shows like:

```
    push    0
    push    5
    push    0
    push    3
    push    0
    push    1
    push    OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    printf
```

The second code snippet is different because you passing just one argument each time, so it gets the correct (that is, the first one) value.